# TextRenderer drawing incorrectly after loading textures

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I use a TextRenderer (com.jogamp.opengl.util.awt.TextRenderer) to draw text to the screen, however after I load some textures (which otherwise work ok) the text is no longer text but little parts of one of the textures I have loaded.

I load the textures like so...

```
    gl2.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, unit);
    gl2.glPixelStorei(GL.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    gl2.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL2.GL_CLAMP);
    gl2.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL2.GL_CLAMP);
    gl2.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
    gl2.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
    gl2.glTexEnvf(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL.GL_REPLACE);
    gl2.glTexImage2D (GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, getWidth(), getHeight(), 
            0, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixMap.getData());
    gl2.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    pixMap.dispose();
    pixMap = null;
```

Why might this be happening?

Comment: Are you generating your textures with `glGenTextures`? It looks like you loaded your image to texture used for font. Make sure you are not binding textures you haven't generated.

Comment: I was not using glGenTextures as I wanted control over the reference number of the texture, thought I knew what I was doing lol. Yes of course, the font is loading a texture into the GPU and then I overwrite it, thanks for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment to Banthar's comment. See above!

I was not using glGenTextures as I wanted control over the reference number of the texture, thought I knew what I was doing lol. Yes of course, the font is loading a texture into the GPU and then I overwrite it, thanks for pointing that out to me.